# Text missing last few pixels

Tags: android

I am writing an android app and sometime the last few pixels of text is being truncated. It is happening on a few different controls in various parts of the apps. This happens on both the Emulator and on my phone.

Below is part of the layout, I have added background colours so you can see that the parent layout is taking up the full length but the text view isn't wrapping the context correctly
[image]

After the 'r' at the bottom then is clearly a gap, yet the 'a' on the top is slightly truncated. Here is the layout

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center" android:background="#fbff18">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/SongRowSongName"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="#ff1217"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/SongRowArtistName"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:linksClickable="false"
        android:background="#ff1217" android:clickable="false"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I know I could just set the width to full_parent on the textview, but this is only one instance of the issue and I dont see why I should have to.
The other main place it is happening is in my tabhost.
[image]

```
intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ProfileActivity.class);
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("profile").setIndicator("Profiles",
    res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_profile))
    .setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

and this is what I am using as the background image selector

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
    <!-- When selected, use grey --> 
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/profile_grey" android:state_selected="true" />
    <!-- When not selected, use white--> 
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/profile_white" /> 
</selector>
```

It just doesn't make sense to me why when there is plenty of space in the parent does it not wrap content correctly.

Comment: Are you doing something funny with your default font?  It seems as though  it is being measured incorrectly.

Comment: For what it's worth I just copied the textview code and I don't have this problem on 4.2 device or emulator. What API level are you testing on?

Comment: @HalR, I havent done anything with the fonts that I can think of, are you suggesting within the application, or a setting on my phone?

Comment: @KenWolf, The app is currently running on 4.2.2 but I used to have it happen when I was building it against 2.2 as well.

Comment: I'd be curious if you had changed either font.  The problem seems symptomatic of a font problem.  I seem to recall having similar trouble a year or two ago.

Comment: I had this situation where my colleague uses some kind of comic sans font (set using phone setting) instead of the standard, turns out some of my text also get truncated at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me the problem was this setting in the AndroidManifest:

```
<supports-screens android:anyDensity="false">
```

After realizing this was the problem I found out that the documentation clearly states:
"For applications that support Android 1.6 (API level 4) and higher, this is "true" by default and you should not set it "false" unless you're absolutely certain that it's necessary for your application to work."

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html#any

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the issue was because I had not specified a minSdkVersion in the AndroidManifest.

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4"/>
```

If I don't have anything, of have a minSdkVersion of <= 3 then the issue occurs.

Cheers all,